Extract multiple parts from a URL using shell
I have a URL like this: bbc:osdb://://user=&pass=abc%sec=true
I want to extract , , , 
Example:
bbc:osdb://293.23.234.55:1234/bbc-dt-af/user=john&pass=pass123abc%sec=true

Should return:
293.23.234.55:1234:john:pass123abc

grep or egrep or sed or awk
This one:
 grep -Eo '([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)|[0-9]{4}'

gives me first two, and in two different lines...
293.23.234.55
1234


By using [shell] meaning POSIX shell, you eliminate a large number of advanced shell built-ins that can help with this problem. That's 100% okay if that is your intent. Many routines need to be POSIX shell compatible. If you wish to allow advanced shell features than consider adding a tag.  For POSIX, consider awk with an initial field-separator of '/' and then split the POST information further.

Regarding "I have a URL" - where? Is it in a file or a variable or stdin? Is it in the middle of a line of text or on it's own line? Do you have multiple such URLs on each input line or not? Etc.... Please provide a [mcve] that covers all of your requirements that we can copy/paste to test with.

If you are matching full urls from start to end, how about capturing and replacing? See if this demo at regex101 helps.

@bobblebubble you should state which tool that regexp would work with. It won't work in the mandatory POSIX tools sed, awk, or grep for example.

Also, please provide a few lines of sample input/output that cover all of your use cases - it's easy to misunderstand what anyone needs given just 1 example to go by.

This question is similar to: How to extract domain name from url?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@EdMorton You're right but I am not sure how OP could use it and also I'm unclear about the question (especially how data looks like, are these single lines that are processed...). However replacing is a general idea that works in many regex environments.

This may be what you want, using any awk:
$ awk -F'[/=&%]' -v OFS=':' '{print $3, $6, $8}' file
293.23.234.55:1234:john:pass123abc

or any sed:
$ sed 's#.*//\([^/]*\)[^=]*=\([^&]*\)&[^=]*=\([^%]*\).*#\1:\2:\3#' file
293.23.234.55:1234:john:pass123abc

but it's hard to tell given just 1 sample input string.

As always nice and elegant answer

@Ed Morton Can you please explain the command. It helps everyone understand.

@KevinRave both commands use very basic, fundamental constructs for each tool, we can't explain the basics of each tool in every answer. Please take a look at the man page for whichever tool you like and if you have a specific question about any parts of the script feel free to ask and I'll try to explain.

With your shown samples please try following awk solution. Simple explanation would be setting field separator to /, = and % and then checking if 3rd field of it matches regex if yes then printing 3rd and 7th field as per question.
awk -F'[/=%]' '$3~/([0-9]{2,3}\.){3}[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{4}/{print $3,$7}' Input_file


It would be helpful to explain the command so everyone can understand

Simple yet effective explanation! Thank you!

Without the benefit of A Minimal Complete Reproducible Example it is impossible to cover your exact circumstance, but it is possible to answer the question of how to parse 293.23.234.55:1234:john:pass123abc from bbc:osdb://293.23.234.55:1234/bbc-dt-af/user=john&pass=pass123abc%sec=true.  (you provide no rule to explain removing "abc" from the end of the password)
There are many ways to do this. The simplest with a single command is to use awk with a field-separator of '/' to separate the parts of the URL and then to use the split() and sub() functions in awk to parse the information. (you can also use match() and substr() functions as well)
A basic awk command to do this is:
awk -F/ -v OFS=: '{
  split ($NF, arr, "&")
  sub (/^.*=/, "", arr[1])
  split (arr[2], pwarr, "%")
  sub (/^.*=/, "", pwarr[1])
  print $3, arr[1], pwarr[1]
}'

Where:

awk -F/ -v OFS=: invokes awk with the field-separator FS of '/' and the output-field-separator OFS of ':',
'{ begin the awk rule definition,
split($NF,arr,"&") split the last field ($NF) into arr on "&",
sub(/^.*=/,"",arr[1]) remove user= from john
split (arr[2], pwarr, "%") split pass=pass123abc%sec=true on "%" into pwarr,
sub(/^.*=/,"",pwarr[1]) remove pass= from pass123abc
print $3,arr[1],pwarr[1] output result, and
}' end rule.

Example/Output
$ echo "bbc:osdb://293.23.234.55:1234/bbc-dt-af/user=john&pass=pass123abc%sec=true" |
> awk -F/ -v OFS=: '{
>   split ($NF, arr, "&")
>   sub (/^.*=/, "", arr[1])
>   split (arr[2], pwarr, "%")
>   sub (/^.*=/, "", pwarr[1])
>   print $3, arr[1], pwarr[1]
> }'
293.23.234.55:1234:john:pass123abc

NOTE if you intended to remove "abc" from the end of the password, let me know. There were no separators that would justify chopping the last 3-characters from the password (other than just randomly chopping 3-characters with substr() or sub() -- that didn't make much sense). So the full password was left in tact.

The dumbest approach is with sed:
echo 'bbc:osdb://293.23.234.55:1234/bbc-dt-af/user=john&pass=pass123abc&sec=true' | sed 's#.*://\([0-9\.]\{7,15\}\):\([0-9]\+\)/.*user=\([^&]\+\)&pass=\([^&]\+\).*#\1:\2:\3:\4#'

Note that I fixed what I assume is a typo in the original URL.
Awk solution:
{
    for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /[0-9\.]{7,15}/) {
            host = $i;
        } else if ($i ~ /user=/) {
            split($i, params, "&");
            for (n in params) {
                if (params[n] ~ /user=/) {
                    user = substr(params[n], 6, 100);
                } else if (params[n] ~ /pass=/) {
                    password = substr(params[n], 6, 100);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    print host ":" user ":" password;
}

Run this something like
cat file.log | awk -F'/' -f script.awk


Did not intend to write a script. But thanks!


Example:
bbc:osdb://293.23.234.55:1234/bbc-dt-af/user=john&pass=pass123abc%sec=true
Should return:
293.23.234.55:1234:john:pass123

I could provide only partial solution using GNU AWK, as no reason for value of pass being terminated at a character was given. Let file.txt content be
bbc:osdb://293.23.234.55:1234/bbc-dt-af/user=john&pass=pass123abc%sec=true

then
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/";OFS=":"}match($0,/user=[^&]*/){user=substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)}{print $3,user}' file.txt

gives output
293.23.234.55:1234:john

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that / is field separator and : is output field separator. I use match string function in order to find where key-value pair of key user does start (RSTART) and how long (RLENGTH) it is, then I get substring of that without 5 first characters (that is user=) and put that into variable named user. Then I print 3rd field (treating string as /-separated values) followed by user. Observe that user-setting action is linked to match, therefore it will not be executed if regular expression will not be found, in which case it will assume user value to be empty string. You would be able to extract pass likewise if you are able to provide values which are verboten in pass value (like & for user), however your example has both a as part of pass value and terminating it, so you apparently need different approach.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
